How to configure a PHP deptrac to restric module-to-module communication?
I want to use PHP Deptrac lib with a layered architecture (Application, Domain, Infrastructure) and modules at the same time. The project structure is like src/<module_name>/<layer>/**. I want to restrict module-to-module communication only through the Infrastructure layer. Is it possible to configure it with a Deptrac? If not, is there any other lib that might help with it?
